# Undefined variable $count

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I'm getting a really annoying error `Undefined variable: count`. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $user = getUserData('Username');
    $sql = "SELECT `Username`, `Uplata`, `Dobivka`, `Date` FROM `kladilnica` WHERE `Username`='$user'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result === false) {
        echo "<b>Could not connect to database.</b>";
        trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        if($result->num_rows == 0) {
            echo "<b>Something went wrong try again later.</b>";
        } else if($result->num_rows >= 1) {
            echo "<table id='t01'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Uplata</th><th>Dobivka</th><th>Date</th></tr>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $count = $count + 1;
                echo "<tr><td>".$count."</td> <td>".$row["Username"]."</td> <td>".$row["Uplata"]."</td> <td>".$row["Dobivka"]."</td> <td>".$row["Date"]."</td></tr>";
            }
                echo "<tr><th colspan='5'>Vkupna Uplata:</th></tr>";
                echo "<tr><th colspan='5'>Vkupna Dobivka:</th></tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
        }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You can not increment a value that isn’t even set before. Initialize the variable with a start value before the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the variable `$count` in the expression `$count + 1`. On the first iteration of the while loop, the variable isn't assigned yet, and that causes your error. You cannot read/use a variable that is not defined yet.

The solution is simple: Initialize `$count` to `0` before the loop.

```
$count = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $count = $count + 1;
   echo "<tr><td>".$count."</td> ......";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `$count` to some value before you try to increment it with `$count = $count + 1`. You can change the `while` loop to a `for` loop and initialize `$count` in the `for` statement:

```
for ($count = 0; $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $count++){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i have another question and i know i'm not allowed to do this but its on the same code ... how do i take all numbers from `Uplata` row and gather to get the total of them ?

Comment: If it's an array of numbers, why not use `array_sum`? E.g., `$sum = array_sum($row["Uplata"])`.

Comment: it gives me error: `Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Comment: So it's not an array, hence there's nothing to sum. I suppose you want to add whatever the value of $row["Uplata"] is to a running total; you should initialize some value before the loop, e.g., `$uplata_total = 0`, and add the value of $row["Uplata"] to the running total in the loop, `$uplata_total += $row["Uplata"]`

Comment: Its giving me always result `0` here is the code `$uplata_total += $row["Uplata"];
          echo "<tr><th colspan='5'>Vkupna Uplata: $uplata_total</th></tr>";`

Comment: Looks like $row["Uplata"] is null or 0 for all your rows.

Comment: oops my mistake sorry it works fine Thank you :)

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest to change

```
$count = $count + 1;
```

to

```
$count+=1;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: The whole problem is that $count is not initialized in the first place.